# How to reduce the time period between two successive scanning in altbeacon

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am working with `ibeacon` using `altbeacon` library.I want to increase the period between two successive scanning.I tried following code.

```
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
```

I want the app to first detect the nearby beacons then do next scanning after a particular delay.But when I tried above code, first scanning is getting delayed.

Answer (score 0):

The library standardizes its scan cycles to the local time on the device, so if you have a scan period of 1 min and a between scan period of 5 min (a total of 6 min), the scans will always start at an even time boundary -- e.g. 08:00:00, 08:06:00, 08:12:00, etc.  If you start up scanning at 08:02:00 it will be in a between scan period, and so scans will not start for 4 minutes.  It works this way so that two app installations using the library on the same device will use common scan cycles to save battery, useful for the default settings.

You can get around this with your first scan by initially setting the between scan periods to 0, then on first detection, change them to the real values you want.  Be sure to use a flag to track whether this is your first detection, as setting the scan periods on every detection would be be wasteful of CPU resources.

Comment: Why my app detects beacon even if bluetooth is off?

Comment: Starting with Android 8, some (but not all) devices allow Bluetooth scans with  Bluetooth off in the quick settings pull down menu.  On such devices, this setting does not actually turn off Bluetooth but merely disallows connections, allowing scanning to proceed normally.  In the full settings app you can still completely turn off bluetooth on these devices.

Comment: Thank you  davidgyoung.